# Trying to store a completed form into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, html

I'm creating a registration page and am currently attempting to store the inputs of the form into an array. I'm using

```
var form_inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("form_input");
```

to store the inputs in the same place, however if I try to alert `form_inputs` to test if anything is actually being stored, it just alerts `"Undefined"`.

```js
function validate_form(event) {
  var forename = document.getElementById("forename");
  var surname = document.getElementById("surname");
  var username = document.getElementById("username");
  var password = document.getElementById("password");
  var re_password = document.getElementById("re_password");
  var email = document.getElementById("email");
  var errors = 0
  var special_chars = "<>@!#$%^&*()_+[]{}?:;|'\"\\,./~`-=";
  var form_inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("form_input");

  if (forename.value == "") {
    //document.getElementById("forename").style.background = "red";
    forename_confirmation.style.visibility = 'visible';
    var errors = errors + 1
  } else
    for (var i = 0; i < forename.value.length; i++) {
      if (special_chars.indexOf(forename.value.charAt(i)) != -1) {
        forename_chars.style.visibility = 'visible'
      }
    }

  if (surname.value == "") {
    //document.getElementById("surname").style.background = "red";
    surname_confirmation.style.visibility = 'visible';
    var errors = errors + 1
  } else
    for (var i = 0; i < surname.value.length; i++) {
      if (special_chars.indexOf(surname.value.charAt(i)) != -1) {
        surname_chars.style.visibility = 'visible'
      }
    }

  if (username.value == "") {
    //document.getElementById("username").style.background = "red";
    username_confirmation.style.visibility = 'visible';
    var errors = errors + 1
  } else
    for (var i = 0; i < username.value.length; i++) {
      if (special_chars.indexOf(username.value.charAt(i)) != -1) {
        username_chars.style.visibility = 'visible'
      }
    }

  if (password.value == "") {
    //document.getElementById("password").style.background = "red";
    pass_confirmation.style.visibility = 'visible';
    var errors = errors + 1
  }

  if (password.value != re_password.value) {
    //document.getElementById("re_password").style.background = "red";
    repass_confirmation.style.visibility = 'visible';
    var errors = errors + 1
  }

  if (email.value == "") {
    //document.getElementById("email").style.background = "red";
    var errors = errors + 1
  }

  if (errors != "0") {
    alert("Whoops! Looks like you didn't enter your details properly");
    console.log(form_inputs);
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting
  }
  if (!email.value.includes("@") || !email.value.includes(".")) {
    //document.getElementById("email").style.background = "blue";
    email_confirmation.style.visibility = 'visible';
    return false;
  }
  return (true);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Login form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Login Form CSS.css">
  <script src="Registration function.js" defer></script>

  <body>
    <div class="loginbox">
      <img src="Logo.jpg" class="avatar">
      <h1> Create Account </h1>
      <form name="login-form">
        <div id="forename_confirmation"> Please fill in this box </div>
        <div id="forename_chars"> Don't use special characters</div>
        <p>Forename
          <p>
            <input class="form_input" type="text" name="forename" id="forename" placeholder="Enter Forename here">
            <div id="surname_confirmation"> Please fill in this box </div>
            <div id="surname_chars"> Don't use special characters</div>
            <p>Surname
              <p>
                <input class="form_input" type="text" name="surname" id="surname" placeholder="Enter Surname here">
                <div id="username_confirmation"> Please fill in this box </div>
                <div id="username_chars"> Don't use special characters</div>
                <p>Username
                  <p>
                    <input class="form_input" type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter Username here">
                    <div id="pass_confirmation"> Please fill in this box </div>
                    <div id="pass_chars">Don't use special characters</div>
                    <p>Password
                      <p>
                        <input class="form_input" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password here">
                        <div id="repass_confirmation"> Passwords do not match </div>
                        <p>Re-enter Password
                          <p>
                            <input class="form_input" type="password" name="re_password" id="re_password" placeholder="Re-enter your password here">
                            <div id="email_confirmation"> Please enter a valid email </div>
                            <p>Email
                              <p>
                                <input class="form_input" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email here">
                                <!-- 
                  <p>Gender<p>
                  <input type="radio" id="Male" name="Gender" value="Male">Male</input>
                  <input type="radio" id="Female" name="Gender" value="Female">Female</input>
                  -->
                                <button onclick="validate_form(event)" type="Submit" value="True" name="button-submit"> Submit </button>
                                <br />
                                <br />
                                <a href="#"> Forgot your password? </a>
                                <br />
                                <a href="#"> Already got an account? </a>
                                <br /><br />
      </form>
      <!-- <button onclick="validate_form()" type="submit"> Validate </button> -->
    </div>
  </body>
</head>
<script>
  forename_confirmation.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  forename_chars.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  surname_confirmation.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  surname_chars.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  username_confirmation.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  username_chars.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  pass_confirmation.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  pass_chars.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  repass_confirmation.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  email_confirmation.style.visibility = 'hidden'
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? HTML forms are typically validated at the level of individual form controls, the form won't submit if all the form controls aren't valid. Check out [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation).

Comment: Simply because my teacher wanted me to do it this way, I already did the way you are suggesting but apparently it doesn't show enough code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("form_input")).forEach(
    function(element, index, array) {
        alert(element.innerHTML)
    }
);
```

this will alert you of those elements

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I tried this and it just shows an empty alert?

Comment: @LucaBriggs whoops had price in there instead of your `form_input`, was testing on my code haha :) try again

Comment: Yes I guessed ahah, however it's still only showing me multiple blank alerts?